# Affine variety of geometric progressions.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $M$ be affine variety $M \subset \mathbb A^n$.

$z\in M  \Leftrightarrow z = (x, xy, xy^2, ... , xy^{n-1}),where\hspace{2mm} x,y \in \mathbb C, x \neq 0$.

I need to find the equations $f_1, ..., f_k$ such that $M = V(f_1, ..., f_k)$. And  find irreducible components.

I solved this only in case $n = 3$. In general case I only found variety with same dimension containing M. Got really stucked. Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a geometric progression, the ratio between successive terms is constant. So, if $z = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$ is a point in $\mathbb A^n$ representing a geometric progression, then $\frac{a_2}{a_1}=\frac{a_3}{a_2} = \frac{a_4}{a_3} = \cdots$.  If you multiply by an appropriate common denominator then you can turn this into a set of polynomial equations.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. "In general case I only found variety with same dimension containing M." Variety generated by this equations contains much more than closure of M.

Comment: In case $n = 4$ this variety contains plain $a_3 = 0, a_4 = 0$

Comment: In fact, it does not. The equation $a_1 a_3 = a_2^2$, which results from $\frac{a_2}{a_1}=\frac{a_3}{a_2}$, is not satisfied by points with $a_3=a_4=0$ and $a_2\neq 0$.

Comment: Y, sure, I meant plain $a_2 = 0, a_3 = 0$.

Comment: Again, if $a_2=0$ and $a_3=0$ then the equation $a_1 a_4 = a_2 a_3$, which results from $\frac{a_2}{a_1} = \frac{a_4}{a_3}$, says that either $a_1$ or $a_4$ is zero. Since you require $a_1\neq 0$, it will force $a_4$ to be zero as well.

Comment: Oh my GOD! Of course! I just needed to write down ALL the solutions. They are not algebraicly independent. In case n = 4 I used only 2 equations but actually I needed all 3 of them. Thank you for help!